# HttpContext.Request.QueryString keys are showing amp;<keyname> for some reason

Tags: c#, http

I am receiving the following UTF8 encoded URL into an HttpHandler on my system:

```
http://example.com/ccredirect.ashx?c=4D49426E6968647C7374&amp;url=http://www.somesite.com/classicweb/portal/cart_return.asp&amp;si=TUsername&amp;ss=BlahBlah
```

I'm trying to pull the different values for bc, url, si and ss using:

```
if (context.Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
{
    buyerCookie = context.Request.QueryString["bc"];
    browserFormPost = context.Request.QueryString["url"];
    senderIdentity = context.Request.QueryString["si"];
    senderSharedSecret = context.Request.QueryString["ss"];
}
```

The problem is that bc gets pulled correctly, but everything after that does not.

I looked at the querystring keys in debugger and they are shown as [1]bc, [2]amp;url, [3]amp;si and [4]amp;ss, which explains why only the 'bc' value is correct, however, it doesn't explain the last 3 keys being named as they are.

While I can easily check for the 'amp;', it seems a bit silly that this should be happening. Aren't the keys supposed to show without the 'amp;' preceeding the name?

Am I reading the querystring value incorrectly? Am I reading the wrong part of the HttpContext object?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you control the page generating the url?

Comment: The URL you're receiving should not have escaped entity `&amp;`. If you own the page/service that generates the URL, fix that to send it with just `&`.